# IF-Directive in Apache Config that calls bash script

Tags: apache2

How can I make an If-Directive in apache config that is executed in case of an external bash script returning `true`, like this example:

```
<If call_bash_script.sh >
  Require all granted
</If>
```

Comment: required all grants only allows the access

Comment: thanks, but that is not the point. The point is, how to I include a callable bash script.